# How do you manage bower dependencies in your apps when there are external fixes prior to releases?

Tags: angularjs, bower

I'm using angular-ui-calendar which is at 0.8.0 in bower.  I see a problem, and I see it has been fixed on the master branch, but there is no new release.  In fact there are quite a few changes between 0.8.0 and the HEAD of the master branch.

I can copy their latest master into my bower_components folder, BUT that won't help anyone else (including jenkins) because when bower_install is done on any other machine, it won't get my changes.

Is there some viable method to deal with this kind of problem that already works?

1. Do I setup my own bower repos and publish my own version of 0.8.1 for my company?
2. Do I setup a script that will apply my fixes to the bower_components folder?
3. Do I add bower_components to git and then check them out the same way I get the rest of my project?

I'm seriously leaning toward the last method because that removes the need for bower to install in other places (bower is struggling to get those 5 9s of reliability)

What problems could ensue if I commit bower_components to my own repo?

(I have a similar problem with ng-grid, so it isn't just the calendar that is giving me heartburn)

Answer (score 0):

I finally decided to commit my bower_components to the git repo so that if I need to make changes to something between releases, I can do that.  So far, so good.  It also helps me remember when I need to add things to the bower.json file (with --save or manually) since those things are now tracked by git, they show up as untracked files.

Also allows me to diff the changes to components, if I update my bower packages, I can see what changed in those packages and how that might affect my project.